# Simple IF statements not working

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am using simple IF statements but they are simply getting ignored when the command button is clicked for some reason.

What am I missing?

```
    If Text4 = "" Then
MsgBox "You must add a GS Reference", vbInformation
Exit Sub
Else
End If

If Text6 = "" Then
MsgBox "You must add a Service Account number", vbInformation
Exit Sub
Else
End If

If Text8 = "" Then
MsgBox "You must pick an advisor", vbInformation
Exit Sub
Else
End If

If Me.Text10 = "" Then
MsgBox "You must select a date received option", vbInformation
Exit Sub
Else
End If

If Me.Text12 = "" Then
MsgBox "You must select a date failed option", vbInformation
Exit Sub
Else
End If
```

To me these should just be checking if a textbox is blank, if blank display a message the stop running the code. But its not working at all.

Comment: Surely you have already debugged your code using break points and single-step execution? If not, please do so. If you already did, please add the relevant information to your question.

Comment: In addition to @Heinzi, remember null is not a zero length string.

Comment: @Fionnuala is right. Use: If `IsNull(Me!Text10.Value) Then`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to replace checking textboxes by commands like this:

```
If Nz(Text6,"") = "" Then
```

or

```
If Len(Nz(Text6,"") = 0 Then
```

The last one works a little bit faster

Comment: I tend to use &, but whatever suits,

Comment: On another point altogether, the OP should use proper names for controls or it will come back and bite.

Comment: Thank you - this worked. Can you explain why mine wouldn't work?

Comment: Because, as said also @Fionnuala, Null is not equal "" (Empty string), empty textbox value is Null, not ""